# iOS how to display in iOS apps the voice pitches when recording a message?

Tags: ios, voice, avaudiorecorder, voice-recording

I am working on an iOS app that would be able to record and play the recorded message.

I would like to display the voice (volume / pitches) when taking. How to do that in iOS and where to display it (inside a UIView? ). 
I didn t manage to find any type of example or source code so far.

I need some help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple provides a nice sample project about recording audio and displaying it :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: this example displays the volume...but not the pitches in wave form...

Comment: plus could I can import this SpeakHere in my project and only call the methods recording recording and displaying the volume of recorded message?

Comment: My bad, I thought pitch was volume-related instead of frequency-related. Good news is, I just learned a new English term today!  http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html should help you using FFT . SpeakHere use a AQRecorder class you should be able to  use directly in your project for recording audio.